# Why does ?.let returns nullable even if it evaluates to a non-null

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin's standard function `let` is defined like this:

```
public inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R
```

Doesn't this mean the return type of let will be whatever the block returns?

Why doesn't this work?

```
var a: String? = "maybe null" 
val x: Boolean = a?.let { 
    a.contains("maybe") // note that contains returns Boolean, not Boolean?
}
```

This complains: *Type missmatch: Required `Boolean`, Found `Boolean?`* Shouldn't it return a `Boolean` since `contains` function returns a `Boolean` ?

I'm sure I've misunderstood something. Maybe someone can help me and other newbies to understand better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`a?.let` returns whatever you do inside the given let-block, BUT as `a` might be `null` you are not sure whether the `let`-block is even called. That's why `x` must be either `Boolean?` or you need to specify what should be returned if `a` is `null`, e.g.:

```
val x: Boolean = a?.let { a.contains("maybe") }
                  ?: false // this is used if `a` is null
```

Comment: Android Studio's style guide also proposes to use an equality check here instead. Not sure what I think of its readability, but it's an option: `val x: Boolean = a?.let {           it.contains("maybe") } == true`

Comment: From a software engineering standpoint, does anyone know if the OP should be using `it` or `a` in side the `let` curly braces? Android Studio also points out that the `a` inside the braces is "Smart Cast" so I guess it technically hides the "outer scope" `a` when it is used in the `let` scope?

Comment: while I did use that `== true` suggestion in the past, I can't really recommend it anymore. As you mentioned already: it isn't as readable. Regarding `it` vs `a` I didn't get what you mean. Usually you would rather use `it` instead of the outer `a`, but I didn't touch that, as the next suggestion would probably be to just omit the `let` ;-) that's why I just concentrated on the `?:` instead...

Comment: `a` is `String?` and as `?.let {` is called on `a` the compiler "knows" that `a` inside the let-block is not-null. That's why there was written something about "smart cast to String". If that variable would be a member variable instead, this wouldn't compile, as then this variable might have been changed to `null` by the time it is accessed... So while it doesn't really matter for local variables it is rather convenient to use `it` for member variables, etc.

Comment: no problem... to be honest I was a bit confused by your question, but I hope the answer is clear nonetheless ;-)